# What are the functions needed to create a pre-sale crypto coin?

Tags: solidity, tokens, coinbase, mycrypto

What are the functions needed to create a pre-sale  crypto coin?

Comment: What do you mean by *pre-sale crypto coin*?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here refer to this part of code i wrote a few months back

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";

contract Presale {
    using SafeERC20 for IERC20;
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    IERC20 public token;
    address payable public owner;
    address payable public wallet;
    uint256 public totalTokens;
    uint256 public tokensSold;
    uint256 public tokenPrice;
    uint256 public minimumGoal;
    uint256 public startTime;
    uint256 public endTime;
    bool public presaleEnded;
    mapping(address => uint256) public balances;

    constructor(
        IERC20 _token,
        address payable _owner,
        address payable _wallet,
        uint256 _totalTokens,
        uint256 _tokenPrice,
        uint256 _minimumGoal,
        uint256 _startTime,
        uint256 _endTime
    ) {
        token = _token;
        owner = _owner;
        wallet = _wallet;
        totalTokens = _totalTokens;
        tokenPrice = _tokenPrice;
        minimumGoal = _minimumGoal;
        startTime = _startTime;
        endTime = _endTime;
    }

    function startPresale() external {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Access denied");
        require(block.timestamp < startTime, "Presale already started");

        startTime = block.timestamp;
    }

    function endPresale() external {
        require(msg.sender == owner,
        "Access denied");
        require(!presaleEnded, "Presale already ended");

        presaleEnded = true;
        endTime = block.timestamp;
    }

    function setPrice(uint256 _tokenPrice) external {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Access denied");
        require(block.timestamp < startTime, "Presale already started");

        tokenPrice = _tokenPrice;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.

Usually, Pre-sale coins or ICOs are conducted off-chain or OTC. All you need is a google sheet to keep the users' addresses and the number of tokens they purchase.

If you want to do it on-chain, I guess you can have a smart contract to register users and have the contract to MINT the actual tokens when it is launched. Your smart contract will be an ERC-20 token without a transfer function.